# jQuery XHR returning error 0 on select platforms

Tags: jquery, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm using the code below which works on some CE platforms but will always fail on others. the message I get back is:

```
ajaxError: 0 error http://site.com/morepath/?_=1314965250990
```

So the success callback doesn't happen

It also occurs in the web browser so I hope some one is able to point out the simple error and why it happens on some but not others.
Good example: Errors in IE9 but works in Google Chrome

```
Data.fetchData = function() {
var i = 0;
Data.items = new Array();

SS.log("Data.fetchData");

$.ajax({
    url: Define.feedURL,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#items").empty();
        $(data).find("item").each(function() {
            var item = $(this);

            Data.items[i] = {
                'title' : item.find("title:first").text(),
                'image' : item.find("url").text(),
                'subtitle' : Utils.stripChars(item.find("subtitle").text()),
                'summary' : Utils.stripChars(item.find("summary").text()),
                'video' : item.find("enclosure").attr('url'),
                'pubDate' : item.find("pubDate").text(),
                'duration' : item.find("duration").text()
            };
            i++;
        });

        Grid.build();
    }
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are expecting an `xml` response from the `ajax` call you should parse the response using `$.parseXML` before using and traversing through it in the success callback. Try this.

```
success: function(data) {

    data = $.parseXML(data);

    $("#items").empty();
    $(data).find("item").each(function() {
        var item = $(this);

        Data.items[i] = {
            'title' : item.find("title:first").text(),
            'image' : item.find("url").text(),
            'subtitle' : Utils.stripChars(item.find("subtitle").text()),
            'summary' : Utils.stripChars(item.find("summary").text()),
            'video' : item.find("enclosure").attr('url'),
            'pubDate' : item.find("pubDate").text(),
            'duration' : item.find("duration").text()
        };
        i++;
    });

    Grid.build();
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem as no data is being fetched yet.
Using Charles to look at the network traffic I can see Chrome makes the request and gets data back; it works fine.
IE9 however does not even make the request; not fine. So its giving error 0, no connection, without even trying?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? jQuery version < 1.6 have few issues in IE9. If you are using older version then try to upgrade to latest version and then see if you still face the same issue.

Comment: using jQuery 1.5.2
I'll try with newer but the CE platform the code will ultimatly run won't run greater

Comment: 1.5.2 has issues in IE9 so must upgrade to 1.6+.

Comment: I tried it using 1.6.2, it didn't work. Still does not connect the request out